# Why does the child div overflow the parent div? (I want an explanation, not just a solution)

Tags: html, css

I have created an example as simple as possible.

```css
#container {
  height: 60%;
  width: 50%;
  border-style: double;
}

#inset {
  padding: 2%;
  border-style: groove;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  Parent
  <div id="inset">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

I wanna know why the `child div` doesn't simply fill the remaining space of its `parent div` with height and width set to 100% (The child div overflows even without the text).

I saw many people asking the same, but they get solutions, not explanations. I'm trying to master CSS which is where I think I fall behind.

How I expected it would look
[image]

Comment: Read into the [CSS box model](https://www.udacity.com/blog/2021/04/the-css-box-model-explained-for-beginners.html) - [Visually explained](http://frontend.webontwerp.ucll.be/assets/css/CSS-Box-Model-Cheat-Sheet-Dark.pdf) - And even [more reading material](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

Comment: Also check [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing) property

Comment: *I want an explanation, not just a solution* --> all the solutions will redirect you to *box-sizing*. Read about it and you have the explanation

Comment: That's why he asked for an explanation. If he knew where to find the explanation outside of Stackoverflow, he would have not created a question here. This is literrally why this site exist: to help people that did not find their answers elsewhere.

Comment: @EricMORAND there are a ton of questions/answers about this. I just found 2 in 10 seconds. All of them linking/containing the explanation he needs. You answer has nothing new here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the HTML specifications consider that the rendered size of an element is computed from the content (or arbitrarily set size) of the element *plus* the paddings and the borders. That is : a div of width 50px and vertical border of 2px and horizontal padding of 10px is rendered as a 74px-wide element.

The CSS property `box-sizing` changes the way the algorithm compute the size of an element. By setting it to `border-box`, the algorithm consider that the paddings and borders are part of the element size. Using the above example, the rendered width would be 50px.

To answer your question, your "inset" div is 100% wide, which means the width of its container, but to this width are added the horizontal padding of 2% and the vertical borders.

More about this - and an arguably more accurate explanation - here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing